# What is the meaning of $p(\cdot)$?

Tags: polynomials, notation

I know that for example: $p(x)=x^2$.
But at some sources I saw things like: $p(\cdot)$ or $p(*)$.
What does it mean?

Comment: See Wikipedia: [Function dot notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Dot_notation). Essentially, $p(x)$ is the value of $p(\cdot)$ when you input $x$. On the other hand, $p(\cdot)$ does not represent any specific value; it is the function itself.

Comment: By the way, shorter questions such as this may be more suitable for asking in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics), which is more suitable for questions that may involve simpler things and discussions.

Comment: Usually $p,p(\cdot), x \mapsto p(x)$ all refer to the same thing, the function $p$. Sometimes notation is abused and people write $p(x)$ when they really mean the function.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I didn't it.Sorry! How do I get to the chat?

Comment: @CS1 Just click on [the link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) and it should open up for you.